# How do I center my carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I read some suggestions here and tried them already, none of them worked for me. So I'm including my codes here to see if someone can point me to the right direction.

1. I want to center the carousel.
2. I want a separate container inside the carousel with text and I want that container to look sort of faded either with an opacity element or the RGB (0,0,0,0.4).. element.

**HTML-**

I couldn't figure out how to post HTMLs here without getting a spacing error, so I opened up a pen in codepen:

https://codepen.io/mahiya-hawk/pen/YvZMbM

**CSS-**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}
.background-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1000;
}
#video-bg-elem {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.navbar{
    background-color: RGBA(0,0,0,0.2) !important;
}
#brand-image{
    height: 100px;
}
a.navbar-brand{
    position: relative;
}
.navbar-nav > li{
    margin-left:10px;
    padding: 33px 10px;
  }
.navbar-nav > li > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2vh;
    font-size: 2.3vw;
    font-family: 'Freestyle Script';
    font-weight: 900;
    color: rgb(210, 21, 84) !important;
    padding-bottom: 0.2%;
    display: block;
}
.navbar-nav > li:hover,
.navbar-nav > li:focus {
    background-color: RGBA(0,0,0,0.4) !important;
    transition: .9s;
}
.navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: RGBA(0.0..0.4) !important;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.content h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 65px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.content p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color: #aaa;
}
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-collapse {
    margin:-7px;
}
/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
    width: 1200px;
    margin-bottom: 480px;
}

/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
    z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #777;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 480px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this rule to your class:

```
.carousel {
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jaziel_Inc. you're amazing. That worked. Thank you!! Can you tell me how I can make the carousel a little smaller because 1200 is way too big, I want margins on both sides of the screen..

Comment: Hey, if you want your carousel smaller just change the max-width property, put the size you want, i put 1200px just as example but you can change tot he size you want, try it, im not an expert but i think is going to work.

Comment: @MahiyaHawk If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.